# phpMyAdmin can't import file exported from command line

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I have two web servers: a live server (Server A) and a development server (Server B). I am often required to export the entire database contents from B and import into A. This was previously done from phpMyAdmin: select the database on B, Export, change the filename, set gzip compression, and Go. Then on A, Import. This workflow works fine, but it's just not efficient.

So now we have a cron job that backs up the database using the following script in a bash file: (shortened for brevity, the other parts are just variables and echo statements)

```
mysqldump -u $user -h $host -p$pass $db_name | gzip -9 > $destination
```

Running the script in the command line gives no errors, but when I try to import it in PMA, it just stops at a blank screen (importer.php). The resulting database is missing several tables meaning it failed to import everything. The file itself is about the same size as the one PMA exported so the only thing I've deduced so far is that it's definitely not a file size issue (the exported .sql.gz file is ~17mb). Could it be that some settings need to be passed to mysqldump to achieve the exact same export parameters as PMA?

The server is running Ubuntu 14.04, phpMyAdmin 4.0.

Comment: @HBruijn yes, it does. Because when we export from PMA manually we set gzip compression as well, and that .sql.gz file can be imported successfully.

Comment: You need to read and show the error logs. If you can import the SQL file on the CLI, the problem is PMA's code.

Answer (score 2):

Blank page may be there due to config option *display_errors = 0*, which is common (and correct) on production servers. Do you have PHP logging enabled? Look into it for error message.

I'm guessing that *memory_limit* config is too low, increase it (and it's really likely here, despite similar dump file size). The other suspect may be *max_execution_time*.

I've also seen a bug in older versions of phpMyAdmin (~ 3-4 years ago) which prevented me from importing `mysqldump`-generated SQL files, incorrectly indicating syntax errors. But this problem has disappeared after an upgrade.

Comment: I'll try setting display_errors = 1 on my development server and see if it shows anything. I've already set the _memory_limit_ quite high but I'll check that and the _max_execution_time_ again just in case. Appreciate the suggestions.